# Changing fare type in KLM

Tags: air-travel, india, netherlands, klm

I have an intercontinental KLM flight with the standard fare. However, due to my own mistake, I just discovered that there is also a student fare with more baggage allowance. Can I change my fare type after booking?

Comment: did you call them and ask?

Comment: Sometimes there are consumer protection laws in your country that force the carrier to allow changes within a time period (such as 24 hours) without penalty.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes and no.

You can (almost) always change your ticket, however in many cases this will be prohibitively expensive. The exact details depend on the terms & conditions of the specific ticket that you have already booked.

For most ticket types a change will cost a change fee plus or minus the difference in the ticket prices. Before you call, you should

1. Determine the price of the new ticket at the time of the phone call (not the time of original booking).
2. Read the terms on condition of your original ticket and understand the change fee rules.

Unfortunately it's not unusual for phone agents to give information that's sub-optimal (for you) or outright wrong. Preparing can be helpful and sometimes you can get a different answer from a different agent.

Case in point: I called twice just last week about the same ticket change and the two answers differed by  over $350.